# Access Update table with selected value from a combobox in form

Tags: forms, ms-access

good morning,
I'm breaking it up with a simple thing

I have a form access that contains a combobox called cboHora and I want to simply update my table (tbEntry) with the value selected in the combobox

[image]

Call my query with vba : DoCmd.OpenQuery "Consulta1"

[image]

But even fill in the combobox before running the query, the following error appears:

[image]

My latest attempt

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: You can't use Me. to reference a form object in a query, you have to use the `[forms]![YourFromName]!Y[ourControlName]` syntax. The expression builder will get you there if you examine the objects.

Comment: @Minty that sounds like a valid answer to me. If you'd post it as such, it could get accepted and we could see this has been answered.

Comment: Hey Guys, I did as directed, but I have not yet succeeded

Comment: I used the following criteria as test:

Comment: [forms]![frm_login]![cboHora]

Comment: What does 'not yet succeeded' mean - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? In first image the query shows form name `fmr_login` and the second shows `frm_login`. I would expect the second is correct and should work. You want to UPDATE every record? You want the same value in two fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Me. to reference a form object in a query, you have to use the

```
[forms]![YourFromName]![YourControlName]
```

syntax. The expression builder will get you there if you examine the objects. 
The form must be open in normal view (not design view) when the query is run.